# Display template in Admin Module of Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, admin

I am new in Magento. I am trying to develop a custom module for Magento Admin panel. My codes are as follows

Location : app/etc/modules

**Digitab_Brandlogo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Digitab_Brandlogo>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Digitab_Brandlogo>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Location : app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/Block/Adminhtml

**logo.php**

```
<?php
    class Digitab_Brandlogo_Block_Adminhtml_slider extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_brandlogo';
                $this->_blockGroup = 'brandlogo';
                $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('brandlogo')->__('Brand Logo Manager');
            $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('brandlogo')->__('Add Brand');
                parent::__construct();
        }
    }
```

Location: app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/controllers/Adminhtml

**IndexController.php**

```
<?php

class Digitab_Brandlogo_Adminhtml_BrandlogoController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action 
{
    public function indexAction()
    {                
           $this->loadLayout();
           $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

location: app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/etc

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <digitab_brandlogo>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </digitab_brandlogo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models />
        <blocks />
        <resources />
        <extraconfig />
        <helpers>
            <digitab_brandlogo>
                <class>Digitab_Brandlogo_Helper</class>
            </digitab_brandlogo>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <digitab_brandlogo>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Digitab_brandlogo</module>
                    <frontName>brandlogo</frontName>
                </args>
            </digitab_brandlogo>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
        <updates>
            <brandlogo>
                <file>brandlogo.xml</file>
            </brandlogo>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

location: app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/etc

**adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <digitab translate="title" module="digitab_brandlogo">
            <title>Digitab</title>
            <sort_order>110</sort_order>
            <children>
                <brandlogo>
                    <title>Brand Logo</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>brandlogo/adminhtml_brandlogo</action>
                </brandlogo>
            </children>
        </digitab>
    </menu>
</config>
```

location: app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/Helper

**Data.php**

```
<?php
class Digitab_Brandlogo_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

location: app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout

**brandlogo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <brandlogo_adminhtml_brandlogo_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="brandlogo/adminhtml_brandlogo" name="brandlogo" template="test.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </brandlogo_adminhtml_brandlogo_index> 
</layout>
```

location:app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template

**test.phtml**

```
ABCD
```

I am getting output like below

[image]

How can I display the template ?? Can anyone help me in this regard?? Thanks

**Update**

I modified my files as below, but it is not working.

Location : app/etc/modules

**Digitab_Brandlogo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Digitab_Brandlogo>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Digitab_Brandlogo>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Location : app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/Block/Adminhtml

**Brandlogo.php**

```
<?php
    class Digitab_Brandlogo_Block_Adminhtml_Brandlogo extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_brandlogo';
                $this->_blockGroup = 'brandlogo';
                $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('brandlogo')->__('Brand Logo Manager');
            $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('brandlogo')->__('Add Brand');
                parent::__construct();
        }
    }
```

Location: app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/controllers/Adminhtml

**BrandlogoController**

```
<?php

class Digitab_Brandlogo_Adminhtml_BrandlogoController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action 
{
    public function indexAction()
    {                
           $this->loadLayout();
           $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

location: app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/etc

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <digitab_brandlogo>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </digitab_brandlogo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models />
        <blocks>
            <brandlogo>
                <class>Digitab_Brandlogo_Block</class>
            </brandlogo>
        </blocks>
        <resources />
        <extraconfig />
        <helpers>
            <digitab_brandlogo>
                <class>Digitab_Brandlogo_Helper</class>
            </digitab_brandlogo>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <digitab_brandlogo>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Digitab_brandlogo</module>
                    <frontName>brandlogo</frontName>
                </args>
            </digitab_brandlogo>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <brandlogo>
                <file>brandlogo.xml</file>
            </brandlogo>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

location: app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/etc

**adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <digitab translate="title" module="digitab_brandlogo">
            <title>Digitab</title>
            <sort_order>110</sort_order>
            <children>
                <brandlogo>
                    <title>Brand Logo</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>brandlogo/adminhtml_brandlogo</action>
                </brandlogo>
            </children>
        </digitab>
    </menu>
</config>
```

location: app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/Helper

**Data.php**

```
<?php
class Digitab_Brandlogo_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

location: app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout

**brandlogo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <brandlogo_adminhtml_brandlogo_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="brandlogo/adminhtml_brandlogo" name="brandlogo" template="test.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </brandlogo_adminhtml_brandlogo_index> 
</layout>
```

location:app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template

**test.phtml**

```
ABCD
```

But it is not working. Now I can see a blank white page in admin panel. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a complete answer:

**Location: app/etc/modules**

*Digitab_Brandlogo.xml*

Looks good.

**Location: app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/Block/Adminhtml**

This folder needs to contain the below files & folders:

*app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/Block/Adminhtml/Brandlogo/Grid.php*

```
<?php 
class Digitab_Brandlogo_Block_Adminhtml_Brandlogo_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('digitab_brandlogo_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('increment_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
}
```

*app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/Block/Adminhtml/Brandlogo.php*

```
<?php
class Digitab_Brandlogo_Block_Adminhtml_Brandlogo extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'digitab_brandlogo';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_brandlogo';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('digitab_brandlogo')->__('Brand Logo Manager');

        parent::__construct();
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('digitab_brandlogo')->__('Add Brand');
    }
}
```

**Location: app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
class Digitab_Brandlogo_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {}
```

**Location: app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/controllers/Adminhtml/BrandlogoController.php**

```
<?php
class Digitab_Brandlogo_Adminhtml_BrandlogoController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action 
{
    public function indexAction()
    {                
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

> The main problem is with the way you have written the XML files.

**Location: app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/etc**

*1. app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/etc/config.xml* Below is how the code for `config.xml` must be.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Digitab_Brandlogo>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Digitab_Brandlogo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models />
        <blocks>
            <digitab_brandlogo>
                <class>Digitab_Brandlogo_Block</class>
            </digitab_brandlogo>
        </blocks>
        <resources />
        <extraconfig />
        <helpers>
            <digitab_brandlogo>
                <class>Digitab_Brandlogo_Helper</class>
            </digitab_brandlogo>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>                        
                        <digitab_brandlogo before="Mage_Adminhtml">Digitab_Brandlogo_Adminhtml</digitab_brandlogo>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
               <brandlogo>
                    <file>brandlogo.xml</file>
               </brandlogo>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

*2. app/code/local/Digitab/Brandlogo/etc/adminhtml.xml* Below is how the code for `config.xml` must be.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <digitab translate="title" module="digitab_brandlogo">
            <title>Digitab</title>
            <sort_order>110</sort_order>
            <children>
                <brandlogo>
                    <title>Brand Logo</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/brandlogo/index</action>
                </brandlogo>
            </children>
        </digitab>
    </menu>
</config>
```

**Location: app/design/frontend/adminhtml/default/default/layout/brandlogo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_brandlogo_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="digitab_brandlogo/adminhtml_brandlogo" name="brandlogo" template="test.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_brandlogo_index> 
</layout>
```

**Location: app/design/frontend/adminhtml/default/default/template/test.phtml**

Looks fine.

I have checked this code in my local machine. Find the screenshot here:

[image]

Let me know if this works for you.

**Note :: FOLLOW THE EXACT NAMING CONVENTION AND FOLDER NAMES AND THE CODE AS MENTIONED HERE in my Answer**

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 3):

Quite a few things wrong here, I'll go through each file step by step.

**Digitab_Brandlogo.xml**

All good here.

**logo.php**

The only thing wrong here is that your filename is different from your classname (logo != slider). Simply change the filename to the classname or vice versa and you should be good on this file. Also, make the first letter of your class and filename uppercase.

**IndexController.php**

Same thing here as logo.php, you've named the file differently from the class, however this one you'd want to change the filename to the class name as you've used it in a lot of your other files. The filename should be BrandlogoController.php

**config.xml**

Because you have a block defined, you want to define your blocks under global.

Replace

```
<blocks />
```

with this:

```
<blocks>
    <digitab_brandlogo>
        <class>Digitab_Brandlogo_Block</class>
    </digitab_brandlogo>
</blocks>
```

Then, under your router, you want to make sure Brandlogo is capitalized like so:

```
<digitab_brandlogo>
    <use>admin</use>
    <args>
        <module>Digitab_Brandlogo</module>
        <frontName>brandlogo</frontName>
    </args>
</digitab_brandlogo>
```

**adminhtml.xml**

Your action is what you want to hit in your controller. The setup for this (on admin controllers) is adminhtml/module_controller_action (if you leave action off it defaults to index), so in this case you want it to be this:

```
<action>adminhtml/brandlogo_brandlogo</action>
```

**Data.php**

All good here.

**brandlogo.xml**

Your tag needs to have the format adminhtml_module_controller_action so let's change it to the following:

```
<adminhtml_brandlogo_brandlogo_index>
```

Then on this line:

```
<block type="brandlogo/adminhtml_brandlogo" name="brandlogo" template="test.phtml"/>
```

You are trying to use an imaginary block type. Remember earlier where we named our block either Logo or Slider? This comes into play here, as that should be the file path you use for "type". So it should look like one of the following:

If you chose *Slider*

```
<block type="brandlogo/adminhtml_slider" name="brandlogo" template="test.phtml"/>
```

If you chose *Logo*

```
<block type="brandlogo/adminhtml_logo" name="brandlogo" template="test.phtml"/>
```

**test.phtml**

All good here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply. Now I am getting a white page instead of **404** error. Could you please help me to debug ??

Comment: **<action>adminhtml/brandlogo_brandlogo</action>**  this creating problem. May be this is wrong.

Comment: Try adding the following at the top of your indexAction: Mage::log("Brandlogo index"); and see if it appears in the logs when you navigate to the white screen. Also, could you show me what URL it is whitescreening on?

Comment: I got below in log.
2016-02-01T06:54:55+00:00 DEBUG (7): Brandllogo index

Comment: I think the problem is in block and layout. Thanks

Comment: I believe that's the issue as well. You can try adding a similar log statement to your Block's __construct method as well to check if it's loading.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Block is not executing. I include `Mage::log("Brandlogo index");` in Block's __construct method and I got nothing in log folder. How can run the Block ?? Where is the issue ?? Thanks

Comment: Try moving parent::__construct(); to the top of the method instead of the bottom, I believe it is overwriting the variables you are setting. Also, make sure that your class name and file name are matching and that you matched that same name with your brandlogo.xml file.

Comment: But the block class is not executing. How can do that ??